# jQuery - Selectable Range Returning the Values "From" and "To"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-selectable

When a user selects a range of values on a jQuery UI Selectable, I want value of the first number and last number to be on two inputs. Does anyone know how to do this?

Example of what I have now.  My jQuery currently only can use one value at a time.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        stop : function() {
            var items = '';
            var result = $("#select-result").empty();
            $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
                var index = $("#selectable li").index(this);
                items += (index + 1);
            });
            alert('You have selected: ' + items);
            $('input[name="bid"]').val(items);
        }
    });
    $("#selectable li").addClass("ui-state-default");
}); 
</script>
<form>
<div>
<ol id="selectable">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ol>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: please show your mark up - selectables don't have intrinsic "values"

Comment: what do you mean with `from` and `to`? which element ia selected?

Answer (score 1):

Selectables don't have a range, as such, but the function below *should* allow you to find the first and last selected element.

How you then convert those elements back to a numeric range is up to you - it'll depend on your markup.

```
$('#selectable').on('selectablestop', function() {
    var $selected = $(this).children('.ui-selected');
    var $first = $selected.first();
    var $last = $selected.last();
    // ...
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/sQwKu/